# Run script only if specific version of node is detected

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

I have a very hack-ish script to deal with a problem present only in node v6.

I have the following in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm run target-2016 && tsc",
```

I want to run `target-2016` only on node v6 (boron), is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with the output of `npm -v`. I'm not sure if I would try and put it all in `package.json`, so maybe an external script for something like this would be good.